# Get attribute set on class 'property method'

Tags: python

I have this simple decorator which sets an attribute `mark='marked'` on the decorated method

```
def mark(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    setattr(wrapper, 'mark', 'marked')
    return wrapper
```

I use it on a class property method like this

```
class Car(object):

    @property
    @mark
    def move(self):
        return "move"
```

Now since `Car.move` is a property method, how do I access the `marked` attribute I created?

```
>>> c = Car()
>>> getattr(c.move, 'mark')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mark'
```

The error makes sense since `c.move` invokes the `__get__` method on the property descriptor which returns a string.

Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: While it's possible to access that attribute (`type(c).move.fget.mark`), it sounds like you probably had a specific interface in mind for this. That interface is going to cause more problems than it solves. Pick a different interface.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica. That works! Without going much into details of my use case, this is what I'm trying to do; I want to use a decorator to `mark` methods of interest. Upon class __init__, I want to find all these 'marked' methods and do something like build a list of them for example

Comment: The usual way to "mark" specific methods is to specify a list of the names of all such methods as a class attribute.

Comment: As an aside, `setattr(wrapper, 'mark', 'marked')` is a weird way of writing `wrapper.mark = 'marked'`

Comment: @epi Sure, I could do that too. I was just trying to separate business logic from administration/application logic by using decorators. In addition, my decorator also execute logic in the `wrapped` function